# Specify type annotation for Python function returning type of argument

Tags: python, dependent-type, python-typing

How do I correctly type-annotate the function below?

```py
def f(cls: type) -> ???:
    return cls()

# Example usage:
assert f(int) == 0
assert f(list) == []
assert f(tuple) == ()
```

Is there a way to type-annotate `???` with something that involves the *value* of `cls` instead of just `Any` or to omit the return type annotation? It is OK if I have to change the type annotation of the `cls` parameter.

Comment: It could be any number of types. E.g. `assert f(int) == 0`, `assert f(list) == []` or `assert f(MyCustomType) == MyCustomType()`. The real use case is more complicated, but I think I will be able to solve it if I get an answer to the simplified question above.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a mix of [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) or [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) and a [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) to indicate how the return type corresponds to the parameter type:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar("T")


# Alternative 1, supporting any Callable object
def f(cls: Callable[[], T]) -> T:
    return cls()

ret_f = f(int)
print(ret_f)  # It knows ret_f is an int


# Alternative 2, supporting only types
def g(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
    return cls()

ret_g = f(int)
print(ret_g)  # It knows ret_g is an int
```

The 1st alternative accepts *any* callable object; not just calls that create objects.

---

Thanks for the corrections @chepner

Comment: All types are callable, as `type.__call__` is defined to call `type.__new__` (and then call `__init__` if he return value has the right type). You can also use `Type[T]` instead of `Callable[(),T]`, if the intention really is to take a type as an argument, rather than an arbitrary callable that returns a value of a particular type.

Comment: I.e., `int()` "desugars" to `type.__call__(int)`.

Comment: The key, though, is as you show: fix the return type, and make the argument type depend on that, rather than fixing the argument type.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the corrections. I tried to get `Type` to work similarly to `Callable`, but I can't get Pycharm to accept it. Unfortunately, I'm out of time now. I might be able to revisit this later today after classes.

Comment: I have been able to build on your solution to get to `def f(cls: Type[T]) -> T:` (where `Type` is `from typing import Type`).

It works in VSCode (it says `ret: int` if I write `ret = f(int)`) and it passes both the `assert`s and `mypy`'s type checking.